# Send email array (foreach)

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, forms, email

I need to send an array of products by email with PHP but I'm getting trouble with a "**foreach**".

This is my code:

```
//Form
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="product[]" class="product" >
      <option value="product1">product1</option>
      <option value="product2">product2</option>
      <option value="product3">product3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="boxes[]" value="Boxes:" class="boxesInput" size="20">
</form>
```

This is the jQuery code to grab the data (I'm working on wordpress and couldn't find a way to do with $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']‎...

```
//jQuery
var productVal = jQuery(".product").val();
var boxesVal = jQuery(".boxesInput").val();

jQuery.post("sendemail.php",
            { boxes: boxesVal, product: productVal } );
```

This is the sendemail.php file

```
//sendemail.php

$producto = $_POST['product'];
$boxes = $_POST['boxes'];

$body = "Order Details \n" ;
```

**This is the trouble** , the foreach:

```
foreach($producto as $id => $row )
{
 $body .= "Product: " .  $producto[$id]  . "\n";
 $body .= "Boxes: " .  $boxes[$id]  . "\n"; 
} 

$mailTo = 'my@email.com'; 
$subject = "Quotes Form";
$headers = 'From: <'.$mailTo.'> ' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $mailTo;
mail($mailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Comment: You have to actually tell us what's wrong.

Comment: Use the super global $_POST to grab the data.  No need for jQuery.

Comment: Well, $.post() is supposed to be an ajax call... for that you would need jQuery/javascript. And as far as I can see, he uses $_POST in his sendmail.php... :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Serj points out, you need to serialize the form data in order for php to understand it. Probably better to use

```
$.post("sendmail.php", $("form").serialize());
```

to send your form data. Another problem is that you declare the variable

```
$boxes = $_POST['boxes'];
```

but the foreach tries to access `$cajas[$id]`? if you change your foreach loop to

```
foreach($producto as $id => $row )
{
 $body .= "Producto: " .  $producto[$id]  . "\n";
 $body .= "Cajas: " .  $boxes[$id]  . "\n"; 
}
```

it should work. Note that your form elements are actually suitable to generate arrays as they only take single values.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery .val will create a JavaScript array, which is not compatible with a PHP array. You would need to serialize in JavaScript and unserialize in PHP:

This is one such function:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/414334-pass-javascript-arrays-to-php/

Comment: The `.val()` returns a string, not an array.

Comment: Serj is wrong. -1.  Before you go excoriating people about reading the docs, make sure you know.  only select multiple returns an array.

Comment: Which is exactly what he is trying to do in this example!!! Look at name="product[]" The two brackets create an array! Yes he also needs to add a multiple attribute to his HTML... to make his users be able to select more than one, but the brackets create an array, again, please look it up before posting crap!

Comment: Okay. There was no need for shouting.